# confused about split by backslash

Tags: c#, split

I am following a tutorial on internet and I have slightly changed the code for my purpose and now its not working. I have selected a path using `OpenFileDialog`and then tried to split selected file by backslash like below

> C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1

and it always returns `form1` instead file name, what am doing wrong?

```
string filename(string text)
{
    string s = Text;
    string[] arr = s.Split('\\');
    string[] dot = arr[arr.Length - 1].Split('.');
    return dot[0];           
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.ShowDialog();
    textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
    label1.Text = filename(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> and it always returns form1 instead file name, what am doing wrong?

You're *not* splitting the string `text` parameter at `filename()` method, but most likely the `Text` property of your `Form` (**note** that C# is [case-sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity), `Text` and `text` are completly 2 different things):

```
string filename(string text)
{
    string s = Text;
    string[] arr = s.Split('\\');
    ...
```

So change it to:

```
string s = text;
```

In addition, as suggested by others, you can use the [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which would provide you this desired logic easily:

```
var result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
```

Answer (score 6):

Your method parameter is called `text` but you split what you find in `Text`. C# is case-sensitive so `Text` must be a property on your Form...

By the way you can use LINQ to make your code a bit more readable. For instance you can replace `arr[arr.Length - 1]` by `arr.Last()`. Not what you asked for but a bonus tip anyway.

**EDIT** Yair's remark about `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` is of course spot-on. Even better than doing the Split yourself and using LINQ to get the parts.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to parse it manually. You have a method to do that:

```
string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

C# is case-sensitive, text and Text refer to different values. In this case, you should replace:

```
string s = Text;
```

by

```
string s = text;
```

"text" being the argument passed to the filename function.